# DateTimeFormatter can parse, but not format for same input

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time, datetime-parsing

The `DateTimeFormatter` for pattern `"yyyy_'w'w"` is unable to format the value it has parsed.

```
val df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_'w'w")
df: DateTimeFormatter = Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)'_''w'Localized(WeekOfWeekBasedYear,1)

val week = df.parse("2017_w19")
week: temporal.TemporalAccessor = {Year=2017, WeekOfWeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=19},ISO

df.format(week)
```

The error is:

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: YearOfEra
  java.time.format.Parsed.getLong(Parsed.java:203)
  java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:298)
  java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2540)
  java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
  java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1746)
  java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1720)
```

Why is this?

Comment: What language is that? Scala? (Not that it really matters for your question, it's just tricky for a Java engineer to read.) If you don't get a useful answer, you might translate it to Java to reach a broader audience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `yyyy` represents the [**year-of-era** field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR_OF_ERA). But [according to javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), there's also the pattern `uuuu` to represent the [**year** field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR) (read those links to see the small difference between them - although for current dates there's not much difference).

The problem is: when you create a formatter with `y`, it uses the **year-of-era** field, as you can see by the value:

> Value(**YearOfEra**,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)

But when parsing, the resulting parsed object (in your case, the `week` variable) is created with the **year** field - as you can see by the value:

> {**Year**=2017, ...

---

The formatter is set with the **year-of-era** field. So when you try to format  `week`, it tries to get this field from the `week` variable. As this field doesn't exist (`week` contains only **year**, but not **year-of-era**), it throws the `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException`.

The solution is to use the **year** field (the `u` pattern) in the formatter:

```
val df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu_'w'w")
println(df)
val week = df.parse("2017_w19")
println(week)
println(df.format(week))
```

The output will be:

> Value(**Year**,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)'_''w'Localized(WeekOfWeekBasedYear,1)
>   {**Year**=2017, WeekOfWeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=19},ISO
>   2017_w19

Note that now the formatter was created with the **year** field, and the `format` method now tries to get this field from the parsed object, and no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

For me, you can't use a DateTimeFormatter to format a TemporalAccessor which is a too broad interface for time. Try to cast it to a DateTime object first.